# Spring MVC multiple requests on singleton

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, singleton, stanford-nlp

I have a problem with Spring MVC. I am using Stanford NLP and I put initialization of it to singleton class.

```
@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public class JavaNLP implements NlpInterface
{
  private DependencyNLP nlp_object = null;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init()
  {
    if (nlp_object == null) {
      nlp_object = new DependencyNLP();
      nlp_object.init("tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
    }
  }
  @Override
  public void init(String name, DataContainer container)
  {
    this.container = container;
    nlp_object.annotate(container.getText());
  }
  @Override
  public void execute()
  {
     ...
  }
}
```

Every request is calling `init(String name, DataContainer container)` and `execute`. Problem is in **70% requests** nlp_object is not initialized.

Inside of a controller:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("javaNLP")
private NlpInterface nlpInterface;

@RequestMapping(value = "/parse", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
  public @ResponseBody
  String parseWithGazetteerinJSON(@RequestBody DataContainer container)
  {
    String name = "Parsing text";

    nlpInterface.init(name, container);
    nlpInterface.execute();
    JSONArray triples = nlpInterface.getTriplesAsJSON();

    return triples.toString();
  }
```

**EDIT 1**

Unfortunetly it is still not working. I think I found where is the problem, just dont know how to fix it.

I put configuration + calling init function into config

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.metadata.tripletws.model" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.metadata.tripletws.controller" />
<bean id="nlp" class="com.metadata.tripletws.service.Nlp" init-method="init"></bean>
```

I have created new object called Nlp and it is just sort of envelope for DependencyNLP (external library)

```
@Component
public class Nlp
{

  private DependencyNLP nlp;

  public void init()
  {
    nlp = new DependencyNLP();
    nlp.init();
  }

  public DependencyNLP getInstance()
  {
    return nlp;
  }

  public void execute()
  {
     ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Then I added this code to the controller:

```
DependencyNLP nlpInstance = nlp.getInstance();
System.out.println(nlpInstance);
nlpInstance.annotate(container.getSection().getText());
nlpInstance.execute(...);
```

and defined private Autowired variable

```
@Autowired
private Nlp nlp;
```

Printed **nlpInstance** is always same. That makes sense in the end. But here is the **problem** I beliave. Requests are influencing each other.

Does somebody know how to make it run?

Thanks

Comment: How are you calling or using JavaNLP? Post the implementation of how it is being used?

Comment: JavaNLP is used from controller by `@Autowired` and `@Qualifier("javaNLP")`

Comment: Can you show me the declaration of nlp_object in your JavaNLP. Is it a simple private member?

Comment: I have edited code and added declaration

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing the `nlp_object` in a `@PostConstruct` method try injecting it as a resource to your implementation of `NlpInterface`

Not sure if this will solve your problem, but if it were me I'd give it a go.

Also, you `init()` method(if you must go that way) should be synhcronized with double `if ( singletonObj == null)` gates outside and inside the sync block.

Comment: Hi, Can u give me example how to do it? My **DependencyNLP** is from external library. Thanks

Comment: when I add the block with if condition also to the second init, it throws an exception **OutOfMemoryError**

Comment: A simple nesting of the `DependencyNLP` bean in your `JavaNLP` bean is what I am suggesting. With the code provided I cannot mock a configuration file that you will find useful. 
You can also configure the `DependencyNLP` bean to call the `init()` method with the needed arguments much neater in an xml conf file.

Comment: what I meant by the double check gate was that calling a `@PostConstruct` method after the ApplicationContext has done it's magic  to initialize a field in the bean is what Spring is there for in the first place. Do that in a config file as a resource to your bean, if possible ofc. 
If you can't do so, on the other hand, see this as a reference [link]) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking).